# Swift 3: Cannot invoke (protocol method) with argument list of type (generic)

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

Given this protocol:

```
import Foundation

protocol Updatable {
    associatedtype E

    func updateValuesWith(_ newElement: E)
}
```

And this implementation:

```
private func update<T: NSObject>(_ values: inout [T], with newValues: [T]) where T: Updatable {

    guard values.count != 0 else { values = newValues; return }

    for newElement in newValues {

        let newIndex = newValues.index(of: newElement)

        if values.contains(newElement) {

            let oldIndex = values.index(of: newElement)

            values[oldIndex!].updateValuesWith(newElement) //<--- PROBLEM HERE

            if oldIndex != newIndex {

                swap(&values[oldIndex!], &values[newIndex!])
            }
        } else {

            values.insert(newElement, at: newIndex!)
        }
    }

    for element in values where values.index(of: element)! > newValues.count {

        values.remove(at: values.index(of: element)!)
    }
}
```

I don't get why I am getting this error message

> Cannot invoke 'updateValuesWith' with an argument list of type '(T)'
>
> > Expected an argument list of type '(T.E)'

on line `values[oldIndex!].updateValuesWith(newElement)`.

After some unfruitful research I am convinced I must be missing something very basic but still can't figure out what exactly.

Enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring input parameter type `T` to be `Updatable`, but your `updateValuesWith` does not take `T`. It takes another type `E` which you are not specifying at all. If you want your code to compile as is, you must tell the compiler what is `E` supposed to be:

`... where T: Updatable, T.E == T`

which is kinda strange because i have no idea how `updateValuesWith` knows what to do, when `newElement` does not implement any useful interface (except force casting it to what you expect it to be). But that would be a different question...

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks man. `Updatable` is a protocol a few classes in my model conform to, they each have their own implementation of the protocol method so they all implement a "useful interface". Does that sound right or is there a best practice you could share?